# What is wrong with this code? Serial Monitor is displaying garbage values

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-uno

The arduino is communicating with an android device using a HC-05. Data is being sent using Serial Bluetooth Terminal application.

```
SoftwareSerial BT(10, 11); //TX, RX respetively
String readdata;
char c = "" ;
void setup() {
   BT.begin(9600);
   Serial.begin(9600);
   Serial.println("Waiting for command...");
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------//
void loop() {
   if (BT.available() > 0) { //Check if there is an available byte to read
      delay(10); //Delay added to make thing stable
      c = BT.read(); //Conduct a serial read
      readdata.concat(c); //build the string- "forward", "reverse", "left" and "right"
      Serial.println(readdata);
   }
   if (readdata.length() > 0) {
      if (readdata == "Up")
      {
         Serial.println("Hello there");
      }
      readdata = "";
   }
}

[Serial Monitor][1]
It shows a random character for any input

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhTh5.png
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check the patterns of the garbage you saw. If you saw the characters randomly regardless of your input, then you should check physical connection and the Bluetooth counterpart SW which is supposed to provide input data. And then if you see the sequence of your input in the output, then you 
 created the problem in the line `readdata = "";`. In the above `if` statement, only one time `read()` function is called, you never guarantee to get whole command string in the second `if` statement. Moreover, the buffer is reset to empty.

If you want to fix the issue simply unless any issue with the connection and interface between Arduino and other device (which I don't know), then change `if` statement with `while` in `loop()` and move `Serial.println(readdata)` out from while statement like below.

```
   while (BT.available() > 0) { //Check if there is an available byte to read
      delay(10); //Delay added to make thing stable
      c = BT.read(); //Conduct a serial read
      readdata.concat(c); //build the string- "forward", "reverse", "left" and "right"
      //Serial.println(readdata);
   }
   Serial.println(readdata);
```

Alternatively, you can also use `BT.readline()` instead of `while`, `BT.read()` and `readdata.concat(c)` like below. I recommend this because the above solution would still have a pitfall based on my experience.

```
  if (BT.available() > 0) {
      readdata = BT.readline();
  }
```

I don't know whether or not you're expecting new line at the end of each command. Then you'd better take 2nd option. If you're using another terminator character for each command, then you should another `if` statement just after read() function call in the first option.